# Find a FloatingActionButton in Flutter test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm running a few widget tests in my Flutter app and came across this problem.

So, the page beeing called in the test is made only by a ListView.builder who builds a list of cards and an 'add more cards' floating button after it (the button is inside the ListView.builder).

According to [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/tap-drag) there's really no secret, you just find it and tap it like any other button widget.

```
await tester.tap(find.byType(FloatingActionButton));
```

But I'm getting a "Bad state: No such element" when the test reaches that line

[This is the full widget hierarchy for that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaMoF.png) and here is the code for the test:

```
testWidgets('Connecting with new machine', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(makeWigdetTestable(child: MaquinasPage()));
  await tester.tap(find.byType(FloatingActionButton));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  expect(find.text('new machine connected'), findsOneWidget);
});
```

Note: The 'makeWidgetTestable' widget just returns a MaterialApp whose 'home' property is the parameter 'MaquinasPage()'.

Answer (score 4):

I had a situation like this where I wanted to find a floating action button from scaffold

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
  body: Container(*** my code ***),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () => { *** my code ***}
  ),
);
```

And my test:

```
expect(find.widgetWithIcon(FloatingActionButton, Icons.add), findsOneWidget);
```